# How to call method of a class inside of the class

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I created a simple class `myClass` and added a method `get_volume`.
How can i call `get_volume` inside of the class?

I always get `Uncaught ReferenceError: get_volume is not defined`

```
var test = new myClass();

function myClass()
{
    this.volume          = get_volume();
}

myClass.prototype.get_volume = function()
{
    return 100;
};
```

**JSFIDDLE**:
https://jsfiddle.net/k01stzaq/

Comment: I get "get_volume is not defined(…)" not set_volume. However get_volume is not defined

Comment: Make a fiddle please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of execution is what's causing your problem. You're calling `new myClass()` *before* the prototype is extended.

(Also, note that you're attempting to reference `get_volume` without `this`. I assume that was a typographical error, but perhaps not.)

Order the code as follows:

```
function myClass(spielname)      //Definition der Klasse "kicker"
{
    this.volume          = this.get_volume();
}

myClass.prototype.get_volume = function()
{
    return 100;
};

var test = new myClass();
```

The constructor itself was hoisted in your original, so the `new myClass()` call worked, but the assignment to `test` was before the extension of the prototype, so inside the constructor there's no `get_value` property until *after* that point (the protoytpe extension).

As a side note, it's common practice in JavaScript to use function names that begin with capital letters to indicate that a function is intended to be used as a constructor. It's not enforced by the language.

Comment: I still get `get_volume() is not defined`. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k01stzaq/1/

Comment: @EdwardBlack it has to be `this.get_volume()` - there's no implicit class scoping as there is in Java etc

Comment: Great answer. On the subject of common practices in JavaScript, camelCase is more often seen, used by the JavaScript APIs, DOM APIs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First declare the constructor and the prototype, than initialize your test object.

```
function myClass(spielname) 
{
    this.volume = this.get_volume();
}

myClass.prototype.get_volume = function() {
    return 100;
};


var test = new myClass();
console.log(test.volume); //should print 100
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: You are using `set_volume`, not `get_volume`

Answer (score 1):

**1. define function internaly :**

```
function myClass(spielname)      //Definition der Klasse "kicker"
{
    this.getVolume= function(){
      return this.volume;
    }
    this.volume          = 100;
}
```

or

**2. add method to prototype :**

```
 function myClass(spielname)      //Definition der Klasse "kicker"
    {

        this.volume          = 100;
    }
myClass.prototype.getVolume = function(){
  return this.volume;
}
```

Comment: The first example shouldn't be encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `get_volume` as a global function, but it was defined as a method of `myClass`.
So `get_volume` method should be called in context of `myClass` object.
Change your code as shown below:

```
function myClass(spielname)
{
    this.volume = this.get_volume();
}

myClass.prototype.get_volume = function()
{
    return 100;
};

var test = new myClass();
```